# JAXB Schemagen (v. 7.0.450.18): change XmlElement name and XmlType(propOrder={...})

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xmltype, schemagen

i am struggling a bit with the autmATED generation of XSD files with schemagen.
First of all i have to tell, that i am working for a project at university and must not change anything in the code of my java classes but the annotations...

So, basically what i have to do is to rename some of my XmlElements and have to bring them into a certain Order. I thought, i could solve this like that:

```
@XmlType(propOrder = { "email", "id", "name", "publication" })
public class Author {
   ...
   private List<Publication> publications = new LinkedList<>();
   ...
   @XmlElement(name = "publication")
   public List<Publication> getPublications() {
    return publications;
}
   public void setPublications(List<Publication> publications) {
    this.publications = publications;
}
```

The default value of XmlAccessorType is `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)`. But when I try to generate the XML Schema using schemagen (in Eclipse and on the command line...), i get the following errors:

```
Property publications is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
```

and

```
Property publication appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant publications?
```

So, to me this sounds a bit contradictory cause it seems like schemagen is completly ignoring what i specified... can anybody tell me where the problem is??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`propOrder` is based on the mapped field/property name and not the name of the XML attribute or element.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so you mean, that @XmlElement(name = "publication") is ignored my propOrder? How is it possible to do both, renaming and changing the order in the same class?

Comment: @user3005072 - `propOrder` is based on the property name (i.e publications) and is completely independent of whether or not you annotate it with `@XmlElement`.